# pass variable into php eval()

Tags: php, eval

I am using php eval() function, below are my statements:

```
$uid = 8;
$str = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uchome_blog WHERE uid=$uid';
eval("\$str = \"$str\"");
die("$str");
//$query = $_SGLOBAL['db']->query($str);
//$result = $_SGLOBAL['db']->fetch_array($query);
```

The output is: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uchome_blog WHERE uid=$uid
That's to say the varibale $uid did not passed.
How to pass a variable into the evaluated string.
Thanks.

Comment: WTF? why do you need an eval at all? Just put double quotes in the assignment statment and forget about eval.

Comment: maybe it is just a simple example bro

Comment: `Caution` The `eval()` language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

Answer (score 4):

According to php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

> The code will be executed in the scope of the code calling eval().
>   Thus any variables defined or changed in the eval() call will remain
>   visible after it terminates.

So, if the variable you need is defined in the scope where you call`eval()`, everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 3):

you can't insert varuiable into single-quotet strings directly. try this:

```
$str = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uchome_blog WHERE uid=$uid"; // double-quotet
```

or this:

```
$str = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uchome_blog WHERE uid='.$uid; // string-concatenation
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable substitution only works in double quoted strings.

Try this:

```
$uid = 8;
$str = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uchome_blog WHERE uid=$uid"; # variable gets substituted here
eval("\$str = \"$str\"");
die("$str");
```

I think variable substitution is something that happens at parse time - it is not done recursively, so in your `eval`, the contents of `$str` is pasted into the string, but that isn't done a second time for the contents of `$uid` inside `$str`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon.
Try this:

```php
eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this too, but it makes no sense and it's the wrong logic for using eval

**Example 1:**

```
<?php
  $uid = 8;
  $OUTPUT = '<?php $str = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uchome_blog WHERE uid=$uid"; ?>';

  eval(" ?> $OUTPUT <?php ");
  echo $str;
  exit;
?>
```

**Example 2:**

```
<?php
  $uid = 8;
  $str = '<?php $str = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM uchome_blog WHERE uid=$uid"; ?>';

  eval(" ?> $str <?php ");
  echo $str;
  exit;
?>
```